# Como convertir una fecha 2019-10-06T18:42:36.264023814Z a 1570387354791 (13 digitos con PHP) y viceversa

Tags: php, date, datetime, unix, timestamp

Intento convertir '2019-10-06T18:42:36.264023814Z'
a 13 digitos para que quede algo como 1570387354791 y viceversa.

Intento hacer algo como esto ..

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles');
$date = new DateTime('2019-10-06T18:42:36.264023814Z');
$date->setTimezone($tz);
echo $date::getTimestamp();
```

pero no me funciona me da un error

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Nos ayudaría mucho si por favor agregas lo que lleves al momento aún cuando esté incompleto o tenga errores

Comment: listo .. puedes verlo ahora

Comment: ¿qué error te da?, aparte de eso ¿qué hace el método `getTimeStamp()`? pudieras agregar el código de dicho método por favor

Comment: ``` Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2019-10-06T18:42:36.264023814Z) at position 0 (2) ```

Answer (score 3):

Investigando un poco pude dar con parte del problema.
Lo que pasa es que PHP hace tiempo dejó de soportar decimales en los segundos en formato ISO 8601. Primero fue reportado como bug, luego fue aceptado como tal [Bug #51950 - DateTime does not handle decimal fractions of ISO 8601 format](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=51950)

```
var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, '2019-10-06T18:42:36.264023814Z'));
```

> bool(false)

La fecha en timestamp de 13 dígitos es similar a la de 10 (segundos) pero que está dada en milisegundos.

Partiendo de esas cosas se podría hacer lo siguiente

```
$value = '2019-10-06T18:42:36.264023814Z';
$point_pos = strpos($value, '.');
$dec_sec = substr($value, $point_pos, -1); // .264023814
$datestr = substr($value, 0, $point_pos) . 'Z'; // 2019-10-06T18:42:36Z

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat(DateTime::ISO8601, $datestr);
$tmst = $date->getTimestamp(); // 1570387356
$ts_13 = floor(($tmst + $dec_sec)*1000); 
echo $ts_13; // 1570387356264
```

Si se requiere revertir el proceso

```
$new_ts = explode('.', (string)($ts_13 / 1000)); // int $new_ts[0] || dec $new_ts[1]
$new_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $new_ts[0]);
$date_iso8601 = $new_date->format('c');
echo $date_iso8601; // 2019-10-06T18:42:36+00:00
$plus_pos = strpos($date_iso8601, '+');
echo substr($date_iso8601, 0, $plus_pos).'.'.$new_ts[1].'Z'; // 2019-10-06T18:42:36.264Z
```

Debido a que el numero timestamp es bastante grande, PHP no puede manejar tal cantidad de decimales. Adicional, al ser el timestamp de 13, de por si va a truncar todos los decimales más pequeños que 1 milisegundo, por lo que habrá un error de precisión al restaurar el dato. Si no es tan importante esa extrema exactitud, podrías truncar esos decimales en el primer paso y facilitaría un poco más el asunto.